# codedui checkbox checked c#

Tags: c#, checkbox

I want to select(check) multiple checkboxes on a html form as shown below using CodedUI  I have tried the following but I am not sure how to select a specific check box, I would be very grateful if someone can come up with some ideas thanks:

```
    UITestControl checkBoxes = new UITestControl(browser);
    checkBoxes.TechnologyName = "Web";
    checkBoxes.SearchProperties.Add("TagName", "TD");
    checkBoxes.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Cell");
    checkBoxes.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "checkboxes[]");
    // checkBoxes.SearchProperties[HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.Value] = "cb2";
    //  checkBoxes.SearchProperties.Add("InnerText", "Checkbox Items:");

    checkBoxes.SetProperty("Checked", true);




    <tr>
      <td>
        Checkbox Items:<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value=
        "cb1" />Checkbox 1 
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]"
        value="cb2" />Checkbox 2 
        <input type="checkbox" name=
        "checkboxes[]" value="cb3" checked="checked" />Checkbox 3
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    HtmlCheckBox mUICheckboxesCheckBox = new HtmlCheckBox(parentControl);

#region Search Criteria for first checkBox cb1
                        mUICheckboxesCheckBox.SearchProperties[HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.Id] = null;
                        mUICheckboxesCheckBox.SearchProperties[HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.Name] = "checkboxes[]";
                        mUICheckboxesCheckBox.SearchProperties[HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.Value] = "cb1";
                        mUICheckboxesCheckBox.SearchProperties[HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.LabeledBy] = null;
                        mUICheckboxesCheckBox.FilterProperties[HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.Title] = null;
                        mUICheckboxesCheckBox.FilterProperties[HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.Class] = null;
                        mUICheckboxesCheckBox.FilterProperties[HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "name=\"checkboxes[]\" value=\"cb1\" type=\"ch";
                        mUICheckboxesCheckBox.FilterProperties[HtmlCheckBox.PropertyNames.TagInstance] = "1";
                        mUICheckboxesCheckBox.WindowTitles.Add("http://localhost:23159/HtmlPage1.html");
                        #endregion
if( mUICheckboxesCheckBox.TryFind()) 
mUICheckboxesCheckBox.Checked = true;
```

Do the same for other two check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends on what exactly you are trying to do.  If possible, add an identifier to each checkbox so that you can more easily identify it.  If you cannot, but you can assume there are always x number of checkboxes in the same order, then you can still make it work.

1. Add identifier

```html
    <tr>
      <td>
        Checkbox Items:<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value=
        "cb1" data-automation-name="firstBox" />Checkbox 1 
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]"
        value="cb2" data-automation-name="secondBox" />Checkbox 2 
        <input type="checkbox" name=
        "checkboxes[]" value="cb3" data-automation-name="thirdBox" checked="checked" />Checkbox 3
      </td>
    </tr>
```

```
HtmlCheckBox firstBox = new HtmlCheckBox(tableRow);
firstBox.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition, String.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", "data-automation-name", "firstBox"), PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);

HtmlCheckBox secondBox = new HtmlCheckBox(tableRow);
firstBox.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition, String.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", "data-automation-name", "secondBox"), PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);

HtmlCheckBox thirdBox = new HtmlCheckBox(tableRow);
firstBox.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlControl.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition, String.Format("{0}=\"{1}\"", "data-automation-name", "thirdBox"), PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
```

2. Find all and iterate

   var checkBoxesLookupFunc = () => new HtmlCheckBox(tableRow).FindMatchingControls().Cast();

   HtmlCheckBox firstBox = checkBoxesLookupFunc().First();

   HtmlCheckBox secondBox = checkBoxesLookupFunc().Skip(1).First();

   HtmlCheckBox thirdBox = checkBoxesLookupFunc().Skip(2).First();

You have to use a function that returns a new search collection because the objects seem to be unable to look up a second time.  I believe it has to do with the internal storage of the query path to the control not being set correctly when doing a find matching controls.

I would consider using an abstraction over coded ui to help write the selectors.  I have [my own](http://codeduiexamples.com/examples/example1) library to help with this which is a simple set of extensions over coded ui.  Using the extensions, you would write

```
var firstBox = browser.Find<HtmlCheckBox>().WithDataAttribute("automation-name", "firstBox");
var firstBox = browser.FindAll<HtmlCheckBox>().First();
```

There are other libraries that provide ability to search using [jquery](https://github.com/rpearsondev/CodedUI.jQueryExtensions).